# Git treat nested git repos as regular file/folders

Tags: git

I have a top level git repo organized like so:

- .git/
- repoA/

  - .git/
  - file
  - file2
  - folder/
  - ...
- file
- file2
- folder/
- ...

How can I get git to `add` and `commit` `repoA` (and `repoA/.git`) as if they were regular files/folders?

Specifically, I want to bypass the treatment of such a folder as a submodule but I want to retain the branches/history of the nested repo (so the `.git` folder is required).

I do not want to alter the state of the nested repo (by committing or merging histories) and do not want to push it to a separate repo on the remote.

The intended result is the same as if I were to `tar` `repoA` and un-`tar` it later.  That is, all the files are intact with no modification or special treatment by git.

Comment: Related: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/84378/how-can-i-create-a-git-repo-that-contains-several-other-git-repos and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47008290/how-to-make-outer-repository-and-embedded-repository-work-as-common-standalone-r and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9674576/how-can-i-get-git-to-add-files-already-tracked-under-another-git-repository

Comment: Also related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40921904/force-adding-submodule-contents-in-git/40922436#40922436

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not directly possible. The `.git` directory has a special meaning for `git`. When you run git operations from inside a git work-tree (not necessarily from the top level) without explicitly specifying the path to the repository (via the [`--git-dir`](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git#Documentation/git.txt---git-dirltpathgt) option or the [`GIT_DIR`](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git#Documentation/git.txt-codeGITDIRcode) environment variable) the latter is automatically discovered by looking for the first ancestor directory that contains a `.git` subdirectory. A `.git` directory that is intended to be considered as regular content would interfere with that procedure.

However, I can suggest the following workaround:

1. In your sub-repository, rename the `.git` directory to something else (e.g. `.git.subrepo`, `.pseudogit`, etc):

```
mv repoA/.git repoA/.pseudogit
```

2. Add and commit the sub-repository directory:

```
git add repoA
git commit -m "Added repoA as regular sub-directory"
```

After this git operations from inside the sub-repository tree will work using the master repository by default. When you need to study the history of the sub-repository you will have to use the `--git-dir` option:

```
cd repoA
git --git-dir .pseudogit log
```

Answer (score 4):

You can look into **[git subtree](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/git-subtree)**.

For that, if you currently have submodules, you can follow "[Convert a git repository from submodules to subtrees](http://mikhailian.mova.org/node/233)":

```
cat .gitmodules |while read i
do
  if [[ $i == \[submodule* ]]; then
    mpath=$(echo $i | cut -d\" -f2)
    read i; read i;
    murl=$(echo $i|cut -d\  -f3)
    mcommit=`eval "git submodule status ${mpath} |cut -d\  -f2"`
    mname=$(basename $mpath)
    echo -e "$name\t$mpath\t$murl\t$mcommit"
    git submodule deinit $mpath
    git rm -r --cached $mpath
    rm -rf $mpath
    git remote add $mname $murl
    git fetch $mname
    git branch _$mname $mcommit
    git read-tree --prefix=$mpath/ -u _$mname
fi
done
git rm .gitmodules
```

(test it on a *copy* of your repo first)

See also "[When to use git subtree?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32407634/6309)", which differs from [**`ingydotnet/git-subrepo`**](https://github.com/ingydotnet/git-subrepo).

Comment: Your first link is now this: https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/git-subtree. It auto-forwards so no big deal. Looks like a pretty good article. I'm reading it now.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32407634/when-to-use-git-subtree

Comment: And yet another option: https://github.com/ingydotnet/git-subrepo

Comment: @GabrielStaples Thank you . I have updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: Glad to help. I just wrote this `git disable-repos` tool over the weekend too to archive a bunch of old projects (into a single parent repo) which need fixing up and reviving at a later date: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62368415/4561887. Perhaps your or someone else will find it useful as well.