# Git: How to make outer repository and embedded repository work as common/standalone repository?

Tags: git, github, version-control

I have a big project(let's say `A repo`), and it there one child folder which is come from `B repo`.  I would meet warning like below when I commit from `A repo`

```
warning: adding embedded git repository: extractor/annotator-server
hint: You've added another git repository inside your current repository.
hint: Clones of the outer repository will not contain the contents of
hint: the embedded repository and will not know how to obtain it.
hint: If you meant to add a submodule, use:
hint:
hint:   git submodule add <url> extractor/annotator-server
hint:
hint: If you added this path by mistake, you can remove it from the
hint: index with:
hint:
hint:   git rm --cached extractor/annotator-server
hint:
hint: See "git help submodule" for more information.
```

I have seen `git-submodule` and `git-subtree`:

[Maintaining Git repo inside another git repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36236484/maintaining-git-repo-inside-another-git-repo)

https://www.atlassian.com/blog/git/alternatives-to-git-submodule-git-subtree

But I don't like them , because they need extra config.

---

What I want is , for example:

structure like:

```
A/
--- a.py

--- B/
--- B/b.py
```

When I change `B/b.py` .

1. If I am on path `A/` ,  `git add` can detect `B/b.py` changed, `git push` only commit that to A repo.

   ```
   git add .   (would add changes under A/  )
   git push   (would push changes under A/  )
   git pull   (would pull changes under A/  )
   git clone XXX:A  (would clone all files under A/ ,    A/B/ is just looks like plain folder with all files, not a repo )
   ```
2. If I am on path `A/B/` , `git add` only add `B/b.py` changes to B repo,  and `git push` only commit that to B repo.

   ```
   git add .   (would add changes under B/ , but not add changes to A repo)
   git push   (would push changes under B/ , but not push changes to A repo)
   git pull   (would clone changes under B/ ,  )
   git clone XXX:B  (would clone all files under B/  )
   ```
3. Once I want to snyc A and B in another machine, just do

   ```
   git clone A
   rm -rf A/B/
   git clone B ./B
   git add . && git commit 'sync with B'
   ```

In another word, A and B act as a standalone repo.

But the truth is , A repo treat B repo as submodule:

A repo
https://github.com/eromoe/test

B repo
https://github.com/eromoe/test2

---

How do I force A repo track all files under `A/` , and B repo track all files under `A/B/` ?   I want A and B act as a self-contain repo , without any other config.

Comment: Impossible with Git. Use SVN instead. Maybe SVN can't meet your needs either.

Comment: I just want to save whole sub .git structure to a git repository... why it's not possible. Submodules don't store your local branches, or uncommited files.

Answer (score 38):

You can use below commands to add files from test2 repo to test repo as below:

```
# In local test repo
rm -rf test2
git clone https://github.com/eromoe/test2
git add test2/
git commit -am 'add files from test2 repo to test repo'
git push
```

**Note:**

You should use **`git add test2/`** (with slash, not `git add test2`).

`git add test2/` will treat `test2` folder and it's files as ordinary folder and file for test repo (create mode `100644`).

`git add test2` will treat `test2` folder as a submodule for test repo (create mode `160000`).

Comment: So that's why `git add .` not work, thank you. Hmm.. If there is a way to force `git add .` add all files would be most ideal.

Comment: Thank you for emphasizing the difference between "test2" and "test2/"

Comment: This is helpful, but what if I *also* want it to add the `.git` folder from the inner `test2/` repo (ie: path `test2/.git/*`) as well, as though it was just a normal folder as well?

Comment: My answer to my own question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62368415/4561887

Answer (score 35):

Probably, git reminded the repository. It helped for me:

```
    git rm --cached your_folder_with_repo
    git commit -m "remove cached repo"
    git add your_folder_with_repo/
    git commit -m "Add folder"
    git push
```

Answer (score 18):

**Update 2 Sept. 2023:** the "proper" way to do it is through `git submodule`s. But, they take some learning and experience. If in a hurry or just archiving projects, use the brute-force methods below, instead. If wanting to learn `git submodule`s to do proper "repo-within-repo" software development with git, see the bottom of this answer in the section titled "More on `git submodule`".

### Manual, brute-force method:

For anyone landing on this page whose goal is just to archive a bunch of git repos inside a bigger parent repo or something, the simplest brute-force solution is to just rename all nested `.git` folders to anything else--ex: to `..git`. Now, `git add -A` will add them all just like any other normal folder inside the parent git project, and you can `git commit` everything inside the parent repo easily. Done.

### Automatic, brute-force method:

Use [git-disable-repos.sh](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_dotfiles/blob/master/useful_scripts/git-disable-repos.sh)

(Part of https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_dotfiles).

I just wrote this script over the weekend and have already used it on a number of projects. It works very well! See the comments in the top of the file for details and installation, and run `git disable-repos -h` for the help menu.

Installation:

```bash
git clone https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_dotfiles.git
cd eRCaGuy_dotfiles/useful_scripts
mkdir -p ~/bin
ln -si "${PWD}/git-disable-repos.sh" ~/bin/git-disable-repos
# If this is the first time using your ~/bin dir, log out and
# log back in now. Otherwise, just re-source your .bashrc file:
. ~/.bashrc
```

Here is the standard usage pattern:

```bash
cd path/to/parent/repo
# Do a dry-run to see which repos will be temporarily disabled
git disable-repos --true_dryrun
# Now actually disable them: disable all git repos in this dir and below
git disable-repos --true
# re-enable just the parent repo
mv ..git .git
# quit tracking the subrepo as a single file (required
# if you previously tried to add it to your main repo before
# disabling it as a git repo)
git rm --cached path/to/subrepo
# add all files, including the now-disabled sub-repos, to the parent repo
git add -A
# commit all files
git commit
```

That will commit all sub-repos, including their (now `..git`) .git folders and all git artifacts, as regular files, to the parent git repo. You have 100% of the control! Want to update just 1 subrepo? Then cd into it and rename its one `..git` folder back to `.git`, manually, then use that sub-repo like normal, then when done run `git disable-repos --true` on it again (or manually do the rename from `.git` back to `..git`), and commit it into the parent repo. The beauty of my `git disable-repos` script is that it can quickly and seemlessly disable or enable 100s of subrepos at once if necessary, whereas this would be impractical to do manually.

Perhaps my use-cases is strange: I need to just commit a ton of stuff into one repo until I can clean up and separate out each subrepo individually at a later date, but it does what I need it to do.

And here is the full **help menu output** of `git disable-repos -h`:

```
$ git disable-repos -h

'git disable-repos' version 0.3.0
  - Rename all ".git" subdirectories in the current directory to "..git" to temporarily
    "disable" them so that they can be easily added to a parent git repo as if they weren't 
    git repos themselves (".git" <--> "..git").
  - Why? See my StackOverflow answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62368415/4561887
  - See also the "Long Description" below.
  - NB: if your sub-repo's dir is already being tracked in your git repo, accidentally, stop 
    tracking it with this cmd: 'git rm --cached path/to/subrepo' in order to be able to 
    start tracking it again fully, as a normal directory, after disabling it as a sub-repo 
    with this script. To view all tracked files in your repo, use 'git ls-files'. 
      - References: 
        1. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1274057/how-to-make-git-forget-about-a-file-that-was-tracked-but-is-now-in-gitignore/1274447#1274447
        2. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27403278/add-subproject-as-usual-folder-to-repository/27416839#27416839
        3. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8533202/list-files-in-local-git-repo/14406253#14406253

Usage: 'git disable-repos [positional_parameters]'
  Positional Parameters:
    '-h' OR '-?'         = print this help menu, piped to the 'less' page viewer
    '-v' OR '--version'  = print the author and version
    '--true'             = Disable all repos by renaming all ".git" subdirectories --> "..git"
        So, once you do 'git disable-repos --true' **from within the parent repo's root directory,** 
        you can then do 'mv ..git .git && git add -A' to re-enable the parent repo ONLY and 
        stage all files and folders to be added to it. Then, run 'git commit' to commit them. 
        Prior to running 'git disable-repos --true', git would not have allowed adding all 
        subdirectories since it won't normally let you add sub-repos to a repo, and it recognizes 
        sub-repos by the existence of their ".git" directories.  
    '--true_dryrun'      = dry run of the above
    '--false'            = Re-enable all repos by renaming all "..git" subdirectories --> ".git"
    '--false_dryrun'     = dry run of the above
    '--list'             = list all ".git" and "..git" subdirectories

Common Usage Examples:
 1. To rename all '.git' subdirectories to '..git' **except for** the one immediately in the current 
    directory, so as to not disable the parent repo's .git dir (assuming you are in the parent 
    repo's root dir when running this command), run this:

        git disable-repos --true  # disable all git repos in this dir and below
        mv ..git .git             # re-enable just the parent repo

    Be sure to do a dry run first for safety, to ensure it will do what you expect:

        git disable-repos --true_dryrun

 2. To recursively list all git repos within a given folder, run this command from within the 
    folder of interest:

        git disable-repos --list

 3. Assuming you tried to add a sub-repo to your main git repo previously, BEFORE you deleted or 
    renamed the sub-repo's .git dir to disable the sub-repo, this is the process to disable 
    the sub-repo, remove it from your main repo's tracking index, and now re-add it to your 
    main repo as a regular directory, including all of its sub-files and things:

    Description: remove sub-repo as a sub-repo, add it as a normal directory, and commit
    all of its files to your main repo:

    Minimum Set of Commands (just gets the job done without printing extra info.):

        git disable-repos --true  # disable all repos in this dir and below 
        mv ..git .git             # re-enable just the main repo
        # quit tracking the subrepo as a single file
        git rm --cached path/to/subrepo
        # start tracking the subrepo as a normal folder
        git add -A
        git commit

    Full Set of Commands (let's you see more info. during the process):
    
        git disable-repos --true  # disable all repos in this dir and below 
        mv ..git .git             # re-enable just the main repo
        git ls-files path/to/subrepo  # see what is currently tracked in the subrepo dir 
        # quit tracking the subrepo as a single file
        git rm --cached path/to/subrepo
        git status
        # start tracking the subrepo as a normal folder
        git add -A
        git status
        git commit


Long Description: 
I want to archive a bunch of small git repos inside a single, larger repo, which I will back up on 
GitHub until I have time to manually pull out each small, nested repo into its own stand-alone
GitHub repo. To do this, however, 'git' in the outer, parent repo must NOT KNOW that the inner
git repos are git repos! The easiest way to do this is to just rename all inner, nested '.git' 
folders to anything else, such as to '..git', so that git won't recognize them as stand-alone
repositories, and so that it will just treat their contents like any other normal directory
and allow you to back it all up! Thus, this project is born. It will allow you to quickly
toggle the naming of any folder from '.git' to '..git', or vice versa. Hence the name of this
project: git-disable-repos. 
See my answer here: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47008290/how-to-make-outer-repository-and-embedded-repository-work-as-common-standalone-r/62368415#62368415

This program is part of: https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_dotfiles
```

### Other, More-Sophisticated Tools:

For anyone looking for a more "professional" solution, these seem to be the most popular solutions, in order with the most-popular (and seemingly, therefore, most-supported?) first:

1. `git submodule` - https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule - the canonical, officially-supported tool built into `git`.
2. `git subtree` - https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/git-subtree
3. `git subrepo` - https://github.com/ingydotnet/git-subrepo

Which of those is the best? I cannot say, but they all look confusing to me so I'm choosing the manual, brute-force option I described above, as that meets my intended purposes best in this case until I can find the time to break out each of the sub-repos into their own individually-maintained repos on GitHub someday.

#### More on `git submodule`:

**Update 2 Sept. 2023:** I've been using `git submodule`s for a couple years now. To learn the basic commands and things, see my section titled "***Git submodules and Git LFS:* how to clone this repo and all git submodules and git lfs files**" in my [eRCaGuy_dotfiles repo here](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_dotfiles/tree/master#git-submodules-and-git-lfs-how-to-clone-this-repo-and-all-git-submodules-and-git-lfs-files). (Also, don't use `git lfs`. See my [question here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75946411/4561887) and [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76567696/4561887), both of which contain explanations and reasons why.)

**Update 21 Sept. 2020:** this article by Martin Owen in May 2016 (["Git Submodules vs Git Subtrees"](https://martowen.com/2016/05/01/git-submodules-vs-git-subtrees/)) contains a good comparison of `git submodule` vs `git subtree`, and generally favors `git submodule`. However, the author was not even aware of `git subrepo` at the time, and made no mention of it except when it was brought up in the comments.

`git submodule` seems to be the canonical, officially-supported tool built into `git`. Although it looks like it has a learning curve for sure, I plan on using it in my next project, now that I'm ready to open that project up and begin working on it again, and it depends on sub-git repos. I plan on beginning by learning about it here:

1. A brief intro by Atlassian's Bitbucket: https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/git-submodule
2. The official `git submodule` documentation here: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules

### See also:

1. My answer on [How to update all git submodules in a repo (two ways to do two *very different* things!)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74470585/4561887)

### Additional References:

1. https://medium.com/@porteneuve/mastering-git-subtrees-943d29a798ec
2. [When to use git subtree?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32407634/when-to-use-git-subtree)
3. https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/84378/how-can-i-create-a-git-repo-that-contains-several-other-git-repos
4. [Git treat nested git repos as regular file/folders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33406739/git-treat-nested-git-repos-as-regular-file-folders)
5. [Git: How to make outer repository and embedded repository work as common/standalone repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47008290/how-to-make-outer-repository-and-embedded-repository-work-as-common-standalone-r)
6. https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/git-subtree

<sub>Keywords: git add subrepo; git add sub repository; git add nested repository; git add .git folder and files</sub>

Comment: Hi, I really liked this answer, and I have a similar use case, but I wasn't able to use your script.
`git disable-repos --true_dryrun` when I run this command, I get a *disable-repos is not a git command* error

Comment: @hargun3045, did you follow the Installation instructions first? If so, and this is the first time making the **~/bin** directory, you must re-source your **~/.bashrc** file, with `. ~/.bashrc`, and/or log out and log back in for it to take effect. Then, try the command again.

Comment: This is to cause `~/.profile` to add this new `~/bin` dir to your executable PATH, as shown here: https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_dotfiles/blob/0c4682cfb96826dc524c5f8c9bdce155f3391742/home/.profile#L36.

Answer (score 6):

I removed the .git in that particular folder. Then after I ran the command

```
git add folder_which_has_deleted_dot_git
git commit -m "Changed to standalone repo"
```

Then after that I was able to track the folder and convert it into a common / standalone repository.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't care about the exact version of B A is using, you can keep your current setting (nested git repos).

You will have the "embedded repo" warning, but beside that, both repos will behave as you expect, each one adding, committing and pushing only their repos.
Note: you can make that warning shorted/empty with [`git config advice.addEmbeddedRepo`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#git-config-addEmbeddedRepo)

Comment: With `git version 2.12.2.windows.2`,  default setting is like using submodule.Just see the example repo in my question , or  you can try to clone  https://github.com/eromoe/test , you can see files under test2 repo not be added to test repo.

Comment: @Mithril yes, that is how it should work: A should ignored nested B repo.

Comment: @Mithril in yuor test repo, all you have recorded is a gitlink (SHA1) of another repo, without having recorded its URL. See my older answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/35334520/6309

Comment: @Mithril That still means that, by default, A and B will act as standalone repo: you can ignore that gitlink record. (Or add `test2` in your test `.gitignore`, in which case, `test2` won't even show up in `test`)

Answer (score 3):

To elaborate more on [rost shan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53372940/10907864).

I had this issue when working on a Rails application on Ubuntu 20.04.

When I run the command `git add .` I get the error:

```
hint: You've added another git repository inside your current repository.
hint: Clones of the outer repository will not contain the contents of
hint: the embedded repository and will not know how to obtain it.
hint: If you meant to add a submodule, use:
hint: 
hint:   git submodule add <url> letsencrypt_cred
hint: 
hint: If you added this path by mistake, you can remove it from the
hint: index with:
hint: 
hint:   git rm --cached letsencrypt_cred
hint: 
hint: See "git help submodule" for more information.
```

**Here's how I fixed it**:

Unstage all already staged files from git for the repo that I am trying to push to:

```
git rm --cached letsencrypt_cred
```

**OR**

```
git rm -f --cached letsencrypt_cred (to force removal)
```

Commit all the files that you have in your current directory:

```
git commit -m "modify credentials"
```

Add the remote repository that you want to push to:

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/promisepreston/letsencrypt_cred.git
```

Push the files to the remote repository

```
git push -u origin main
```

**OR**

```
git push -u origin master
```

That's all.

**I hope this helps**

Answer (score 3):

I wanted to add the other repository simply as a directory/module with a bunch of files, so I just deleted the `.git` file inside the other repository and it worked like a charm!

Modifying the snippet from Marina Liu's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47008290/git-how-to-make-outer-repository-and-embedded-repository-work-as-common-standal/47031933#47031933) above:

```
# In local test repo
rm -rf test2
git clone https://github.com/eromoe/test2

cd test2
rm -rf .git
cd ..

git add test2/
git commit -m "add files from test2 repo to test repo"
git push origin main
```

**Disclaimer**: I am not a `git` expert. The above solution worked for my case and so, I posted it. Kindly comment below if this solution introduces any undesirable effect in the repository.

Answer (score 3):

You have added a git repository inside another git repository

The outer git repository will ignore the inner git repository.

The inner git repository is known as a submodule.

Let's say you have these files and directories

```
project 
   |- file1.html
   |- file2.css
   |- resources
       |- info1.json
       |- info2.json
```

If you create a git repository in the project directory, and there's a git repository in the resources directory, all the files inside the resources directory will be ignored by the git repository in the project directory.

A git repo inside another git repo is called a submodule. In other words, a directory with a git repository in, is inside another directory, also with a git repository in. The submodule doesn't have to be in the immediate subdirectory, it can be one or two or more levels above.

Sometimes this is what you want to do, but if what you want to do is to collect files from more than one directory together in to one repository, you only want one git repository for the entire project. So a submodule is not what you want to happen.

When a git repo is created, it created a hidden directory called .git and that's how the git tool knows it's working with a git repository. All of the info about your past versions of code, the location of the GitHub remote etc.. are stored in files in this .git directory.

If you have a git repo in the project directory, and another one in the resources directory, your file system will actually look like this,

```
 project 
   |- .git
   |- file1.html
   |- file2.css
   |- resources
       |- .git
       |- info1.json
       |- info2.json
```

If you add and commit files from the project directory, you'll see an entry for the resources directory under files you've added and committed, but the info1.json and info2.json files will not be added.

If you want the project directory to have one git repo with everything in, follow these steps.

In the resources directory (the inner directory with a git repo in): **delete the .git folder.** You will need to enable hidden files to see this in explorer / finder.

Use a command prompt or git bash (windows) or terminal (mac, linux) and navigate to the project directory. You need to be in the directory above the one with the submodule - so in this example, the project directory (the outer directory, the one that should contain all the files). Then run the command

**git rm --cached resources**

**but replace resources with your own directory name. The --cached part is really important, if you miss it out it will irreversably delete your resources directory!**

Now you should be able to use the git add command to add all of the files in the resources directory to the main project's repository, and commit those files.

Answer (score 1):

These are all great solutions, but if, like me, you're just trying to push a bunch of stuff to github as a backup (my ubuntu vm broke and I can only access things from the terminal), one simpler solution that could work well enough in many cases is to just archive your files. If you have 7zip or something a simple `7z a backup.7z *` will do the trick. And then you can add, commit, and push that `backup.7z` file