# Pushing the Project to Gitlab but I can not push layouts

Tags: gitlab, push

I have a project that I want to push to Gitlab . After pushing, I have a warning about layouts, like below:

> warning: adding embedded git repository: app/src/main/res/layout hint:
>   You've added another git repository inside your current repository.

After push, I checked the project and saw that the layout folder is empty.
After some search I found that I should use submodule. but, I do not want to use submodule and I want to push entire project to one repository.

What should I do to change this warning ?

Comment: Maybe your layout folder already have git configure. remove that git from layout folder and then try to push repo again.
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47008290/how-to-make-outer-repository-and-embedded-repository-work-as-common-standalone-r]

Comment: This answer is true. Thanks